# One way LAN messaging

Tags: chat, communication, lan

I'm looking for one way LAN messaging software for Windows. I have found [this](https://www.cezeo.com/products/lantalk-net/). It does exactly what I need, but for our network, (approx 400 users) it is just too expensive. My requirement are:

- one way communication (I need a program to send notifications to colleagues but I don't want them to use this app to talk to each other)
- working over LAN even without internet connection.
- it should be possible to form groups of users.
- it's best to be free.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you looking for a one way only tool, or a chat tool? Is this for Windows, Mac, and/or Linux?

Comment: One way only on windows